# Disable single posts, but keep archive

Tags: php, posts

I need to completely disable single post pages, but keep the archive. I don't only want to remove the links from the archive, but fully disable the single post pages, so that they cannot be reaced by entering the specific urls. I tried

```
add_action('register_post_type_args', function ($args, $postType) {
if ($postType !== 'post'){
    return $args;
}

$args['publicly_queryable'] = false;
return $args;
}, 99, 2);
```

but it is not working, everything can be reached like before. What do I need to change?

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be forcefully setting 404 status for single post. Please check following example. In case of singular post, query status is set to 404.

```
function theme_slug_customize_single_post() {
  if ( is_singular( 'post' ) ) {
    global $wp_query;
    $wp_query->set_404();
    status_header(404);
  }
}
add_action( 'wp', 'theme_slug_customize_single_post' );
```

Comment: Is this a good way?